InstallShield .ism XML documentation
Is there any documentation describing the format of the InstallShield .ism files? InstallShield .ism files can be saved either in a binary format, or as XML. I am interested in the XML format.
What is the meaning of the various XML elements?
Is the is.xsl a publicly available file, or a proprietary file?
The setup.exe that I am trying to understand was created using IS_v2016. The .ism file is using schema 777, from what I read online that means IS_v2016, the same IS version. My setup.exe is somewhat (few months) newer than my .ism, but it should be close enough.
One of the questions on my mind is what the DOCTYPE msi in the snippet below means. I was unable to capture an MSI file in the temp folder when running the setup.exe . Is my .ism InstallScript-MSI or InstallScript-non-MSI?
Context:
I want to understand my .ism enough so that I can rewrite the installer using some different technology, probably WIX.
Example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="is.xsl" ?>
<!DOCTYPE msi [
   <!ELEMENT msi   (summary,table*)>
   <!ATTLIST msi version    CDATA #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST msi xmlns:dt   CDATA #IMPLIED
                 codepage   CDATA #IMPLIED
                 compression (MSZIP|LZX|none) "LZX">


Not sure what you want to achieve. InstallShield is a proprietary product and you need the software in order to work properly with the files. The exact file format is proprietary XML and it is also version-dependent, e. g. the latest version of InstallShield is the 2024 version. Therefore you wont't find an abstract XML specification fitting for any InstallShield project.
An overview of the documentation of each InstallShield version can be found via the Flexera website at https://docs.revenera.com/?product=InstallShield.
Detailled information about e. g. InstallShield 2024 and a full reference of the InstallShield scripting language can be found here: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield/helplibrary/IHelpContents.htm#introduction_1092564648_1001629.
The file is.xsl is a tool to view the XML project file in a web-browser (by converting it to a more human-readable format). More information about this topic, can be found in an InstallShield hint (also from Flexera): https://resources.flexera.com/web/media/documents/xml_dvs.pdf.
Anyhow, due to licensing issue I personally would not recommend InstallShield any more for new projects. Use Windows Installer Xml (WiX) instead! It's freely available as NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WiX

I want to understand my .ism enough so that I can rewrite the installer using some different technology, probably WIX.
